# Comparator.comparing to sort a list using nested object's field

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, comparator

I want to sort a list which looks like below based on a attribute of nested class.

```
class Test {
      private NestedClass nestedClass;
      private AnotherNested anotherNested;
      private int id;
     //getter, setter
}

class NestedClass {
    private String field1;
    private int field2;
    // getter,setter
}

List<Test> tests = service.getTests(string something);
```

I want to sort tests by the `field1` in `nestedClass` using **Comparator.comparing**. I tried below which does not seem to be working

```
tests.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(test->test.getNestedClass().getField1()));
```

Comment: what do you mean not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `sorted` API on a `Stream` but not collecting the sorted stream into a `List<Test>` further. No operation is performed whatsoever by the line of code you've used for the same reason.

To perform an in place operation, you should rather be calling `sort` API on the `List` interface as:

```
tests.sort(Comparator.comparing(test -> test.getNestedClass().getField1()));
```

Or else complete the stream operation collecting the data as a terminal operation as in :

```
List<Test> sortedTests = tests.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(test->test.getNestedClass().getField1()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I am seeing java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList.sort(Collections.java:1331) for your answer @Naman

Comment: @Jacob that would rely on the type of `List` returned by your `service.getTests` call. If it's unmodifiable, the updated solution shall work for you. See the edit.